Authorize an org failed in VS code but not in the browser
Problem statement : I am able to create a project, but when I try to authenticate an organisation using VScode, it takes me to a browser where I have to enter my credentials. 'Authentication sucessfully' appears once the credentials are entered, however in VScode, it continues to display "inprogress," and if I cancel it, I get the following problems.

Error Detail: 9:53:02.435 sf org:login:web --alias Dev --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
(node:4380) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use node --trace-deprecation ... to show where the warning was created)
10:10:48.563 sf org:login:web --alias Dev --instance-url https://login.salesforce.com --set-default
ended with exit code 1

update 2024-12-19: the GitHub issue has been closed with this comment

this issue has been addressed in 2.69.14 (December 11, 2024). Thx!


The deprecation warning message has been happening from time to time since a few months. If you receiving it once, it will appear for almost all sf commands.
It is linked to an open issue on GitHub The Salesforce CLI outputs "DeprecationWarning: The punycode module is deprecated." after every sf command
If you are using Windows and installed SF CLI using windows installer, uninstall it, then reinstall it again with NPM via command npm install @salesforce/cli -g
Reinstalling via npm worked for me.
Check the other recommendations on the issue for more details and comment on the issue directly if needed
